# php, curl, headers and content-type

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I am having some trouble working with curl and headers returned by servers.

1) My php file on my_website.com/index.php   looks like this (trimmed version):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://my_content_server.com/index.php';

//Open connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

The php file on my_content_server.com/index.php  looks like this:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found - Archive Empty");
echo "Some content > 600 words to make chrome/IE happy......";
?>
```

I expect that when I visit my_website.com/index.php,  I should get a 404, but that is not happening.

What am I doing wrong?

2) Basically what I want to achieve is:

my_content_server.com/index.php will decide the content type and send appropriate headers, and my_website.com/index.php should just send the same content-type and other headers (along with actual data) to the browser.  But it seems that my_website.com/index.php is writing its own headers? (Or maybe I am not understanding the working correctly).

regards,
JP

Comment: `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found - Archive Empty'); exit;`

Comment: Does exit matter if it is the last statement?  (I guess I am allowed to echo after sending 404 header?).

Comment: i guess u trying to return the header from http://my_content_server.com/index.php? `... ob_start(); $header = obj_get_contents()// your header; ob_end_clean(); header($header); echo "additional message"; ` and use the `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);` suggested by @stillstanding

Comment: Yes, you can echo anything after 404. Many nice 404 pages are done in this way.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request

Comment: You should set the response code using http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert before `curl_exec()`:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
```

Instead of just `echo`'ing the result, forward the headers to the client as well:

```
list($headers,$content) = explode("\r\n\r\n",$result,2);
foreach (explode("\r\n",$headers) as $hdr)
    header($hdr);
echo $content;
```

Comment: This does have an affect, however, not what I desired. After setting this flag, the header is displayed verbatim by  my_website.com/index.php.  HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found - Archive Empty Date: Wed, 10 Nov 2010 08:09:30 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8g X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.6 Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 282 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html.    I client browses still does not receive 404 error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This has some error which I am unable to trace. I turned display_errors on, and get this: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/index.php on line 42 Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected. in /var/www/index.php on line 44.    42 line is the "explode" line and 44 the header($hdr) one.

Comment: Whoa. Got it. '\r\n\r\n' and '\r\n' should be "\r\n\r\n" and "\r\n". Works like a charm.  Btw, can there be issues with redirects or "continue" headers  or keep alive connections with this approach?

Comment: If my_website.com/index.php receives a redirect (and other headers), it will also forward that same header to the client.

Comment: As far as the content server is concerned, the cURL client is just another HTTP client. And the connection is not pass-thru. You now have 2 different HTTP connections on the cURL client side - one to the content server, another to the end-user. So it's acting as a proxy. You may want to filter the headers if that's not the behavior you expect.

Comment: Thanks stillstanding for solving the problem.

Comment: You may want to filter some of the headers. For example "Transfer-Encoding:" may lead to problems if you just pass it through!