# parallel task with curl

Tags: php

```
$nodes = array($url1, $url2, $url3);
$node_count = count($nodes);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for ($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++) {
    $url = $nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}
do {
    curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
} while ($running > 0);

for ($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++) {
    $results[] = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[$i]);
}
print_r($results);
//Is this part really parallel ?

for ($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++) {

    $results[] = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[$i]);
    #now i want to perform one task again parallely with all url .

    $var = 1; # it will increase till condition is satisfied
    #in task lets say i want to to change all url to  $url1%20something$var
    #parallely with  others url also $url2%20something$var , $url3%20something$var

    # lets say for $var=6
    #when condition after fetching for $res=curl_multi_get_content($url1%20something$var), $res==true is satisfied , it will stop for one url .
    //till for others it will continue .
    #insort task is loop with parallel . possible ? how ?

}
```

insort task is loop with parallel . possible ? how ?
i explained what i want in code . . in last for loop after fetching content for each urls , i want to again do some task for all url parallely ?

is that possible ? please can anyone tell me how with curl ? i tried some but i failed .

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311112/4444824

Comment: "parallely" isn't a word. Perhaps you mean "in parallel" ?