# What is the simplest way to implement Parallel cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have a .php file with following codes. I wanted to make the curl request in parallel because in below code - every request is taking minimum 1 second. I wanted to process at least 10 requests within this time. How can I achieve this?

```
<?php
$data = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$count = count($data);
for( $i = 0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    $mob=$data[$i];
    $url = "http://127.0.0.1/test.php?category=243&to=$mob";
    echo $url."\n";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $htmlText = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

`test.txt` file have some data like below:

```
100100
200200
300300
......
......
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parallel curl requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308779/php-parallel-curl-requests)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use: [curl_multi_add_handle](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php)

Although you could also use exec, but this would be more difficult