# Why PHP Curl with a while loop produces a 504 Timeout?

Tags: php, curl, http-post, php-curl, fgetcsv

Good day I'm trying to create some virtual cards with an array of json from a CSV file.  The CSV file have 100 cards that I'm trying to create.  If I try to post the full 100 lines in the csv file I get a 504 error.  If I post it with only 10 lines the post is successful printing the response.

I'm hosting this on a shared hosting account.  I cannot change the http.conf or any other apache configuration.

My CSV file

```
First,Lasy,DOB,Phone,Email,Address 1,Address 2,City,State,Zip,Country
John,Doe,1/1/2000,5555555555,something@example.com,123 something street,,Atlanta,GA,00000,US
Jimmy,Doe,1/1/2000,5555555555,something@example.com,123 something street,,Atlanta,GA,00000,US
```

My Code. . .

```
$handle = fopen('sgvc.csv', 'r')
$header = fgetcsv($handle);
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false){

        $sv = '{
      "VirtualCards":[{  
      "FirstName":"'.$data[0].'",  
     "LastName":"'.$data[1].'",  
     "DateOfBirth":"'.$data[2].'", 
    "Phone":"'.$data[3].'", 
     "Email":"'.$data[4].'", 
     "ProfileAddress":{  
      "AddressLine1":"'.$data[5].'", 
       "AddressLine2":"'.$data[6].'", 
       "City":"'.$data[7].'", 
       "State": "'.$data[8].'", 
       "PostalCode":"'.$data[9].'", 
       "Country":"'.$data[10].'", 
       }, 
      "GroupId": ""}]

     }';

        echo $sv;
       $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $sv);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 900);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: token ','Content-Type: application/json'));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

My echoed json..

```
    { "VirtualCards":[{ "FirstName":"John", "LastName":"Doe", "DateOfBirth":"2/3/1981", "Phone":"5555555555", "Email":"something@example.com", "ProfileAddress":{ "AddressLine1":"123something rd", "AddressLine2":"", "City":"atlanta", "State": "GA", "PostalCode":"00000", "Country":"US", }, "GroupId": "123",}] }
{ "VirtualCards":[{ "FirstName":"John", "LastName":"Doe", "DateOfBirth":"2/3/1981", "Phone":"5555555555", "Email":"something@example.com", "ProfileAddress":{ "AddressLine1":"123something rd", "AddressLine2":"", "City":"atlanta", "State": "GA", "PostalCode":"00000", "Country":"US", }, "GroupId": "123",}] } //...array of json
```

I have tried to understand this.  Such as putting this in data chunks or using stream_context_create.  Is there a better way to do this such as 10 lines at a time?

Answer (score 0):

504 is the gateway timeout error. Since your code is sending requests sequentially, the php script is probably taking too long to answer. You may try to print something and `flush()` it to the client or make the curl requests in parallel.

You may use `curl_multi` to run the curl requests in parallel. There is a code example here: [PHP Parallel curl requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308779/php-parallel-curl-requests)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but it wasn't PHP related at all. After I'd increased the timeouts in my PHP code, I was still getting it, until I realized I needed to add

```
Timeout 180
```

to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf for Apache.