# Efficient way to test dead 10,000+ URLs stored on database using PHP/MS SQL/Task Scheduler

Tags: php, iis, cron, scheduled-tasks, sqlsrv

I have a database table which holds 10,000+ entries with URLs. I am testing to see whether URLs are active or dead using get_headers() PHP function and I have set a task which runs every hour (entries are tested in chuncks of 500 approx.)

It works fine but, it times out because, it has to enquire lots of entries at once.

Is there a better way of doing this and reduce server load at the same time?
I also tried CURL but, it has the same timeout issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you checking every URL every hour?

Comment: I'm testing approx. 500 URLs every hour to avoid server load.

Comment: You've got to define a reasonable amount of time that a connection should take before you consider the URL dead. Even if you choose an aggressive value like just 5 seconds, a serialized check like this will take 42 minutes to get 500 failures. You'll likely need to parallelize the requests, perhaps via curl_multi_exec(). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308779/php-parallel-curl-requests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this comment on PHP's documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.get-headers.php#117189) it may be better to use cURL.

- I would store in the DB a timestamp of the last URL check for each entry.
- Create a cron job that triggers a PHP script every minute or every x minutes.

The PHP cron task:

- I would query the database to get all the links with a timestamp older than one day (or x hours), sorted by older first and a limit of let's say 20 links or more.
- Loop over these links and check each link with cURL:

  - Set correct cURL `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` timeouts so that the check can be done but without exceeding a long time also. Perhaps 5 to 10 seconds?
  - Check the URL and update the timestamp once it's done.
  - See what `getrusage()` returns you to see if you are soon arriving at the `ini_get('max_execution_time')` value. Or create your own timer with `microtime()`. But the idea is to break the loop if needed to avoid the script to be suddenly killed.

You could then try to improve speed by using `curl_multi_*()` routines. I just didn't find a nice solution where you read the result of each finished handle in order to update the DB. If you have to wait for all requests to finish then why not making some packages of URL requests and run them all. This is what I tried quickly, but by reading the result (which would not be your case):

```php
<?php

define('TIMEOUT', 8);

$urls = [
    'https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-multi-select.php',
    'https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/fr/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/testen.html',
    'https://ofsp-coronavirus.ch/tester/',
    'https://www.liguepulmonaire.ch/nc/fr/maladies-et-consequences/bpco/test-de-risque-bpco.html',
    'https://www.ge.ch/covid-19-se-faire-tester/faire-test-covid-19',
    'https://www.gsi.be.ch/fr/start/themen/coronavirus/testen/wo-kann-ich-einen-covid-19-test-machen-.html',
    'https://diagnostics.roche.com/ch/fr/products/params/sars-cov-2-rapid-antigen-nasal-test.html',
    'https://www.unispital-basel.ch/fr/patients-proches/votre-sejour/massnahmen-coronavirus/test-coronavirus/',
    'https://www.insel.ch/fr/patients-et-visiteurs/coronavirus/test-du-covid-dans-linsel-gruppe',
    'https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/en/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/testen.html',
    'https://www.fr.ch/sante/covid-19/test-covid-19-liste-des-pharmacies-autorisees',
    'https://www.fr.ch/document/425951',
    'https://www.m3-test.ch/',
    'https://www.ehnv.ch/covid-19',
    'https://covid-19testing.genepredictis.com/',
    'https://www.vd.ch/themes/mobilite/automobile/test-schuhfried/',
    'https://www.hirslanden.ch/fr/corporate/campagne/covid-19-test/tests-repetitifs-preventifs-entreprises-ecoles.html',
];

$multi_handle = curl_multi_init();

$handles = [];

foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    $handles[$i] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($handles[$i], [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => TIMEOUT,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => TIMEOUT,
    ]);
    curl_multi_add_handle($multi_handle, $handles[$i]);
}

$running = null;

do {
    curl_multi_exec($multi_handle, $running);
    usleep(1000);
} while ($running > 0);

$results = [];

foreach ($handles as $i => $handle) {
    $results[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($handle);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($multi_handle, $handle);
}

curl_multi_close($multi_handle);

var_export($results);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I stuck with get_headers() function to detect dead URLs, and triggered the cron job every minute and also set to test only 5 entries at once. The timeout issue no longer exists.