# 304 not modified header and SAME ORIGIN policy

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to see if an external image is sending back the 304 not modfied header, is this able to be done on my server or will this violate the same origin policy?

Comment: SOP only counts if you're doing it client-side.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to test whether the remote server supports conditional requests (e.g., is it _possible_ to receive 304), or do you want to know about the state of the client's cache?

Comment: the state of the clients cache

Answer (score 0):

The same origin policy can only make problems when using ajax. Images, javascripts etc. aren't affected by this policy, which only exists in browsers.

Simply send an curl request with the headers and then read the headers. See also: [Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request)