# Getting the Request URL from the browser and printing it on the screen

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, codeigniter

[image]

I want to get the Request URL from the browser as in the picture and print it on the screen. How can I do this with codeigniter 4, PHP, js?

Comment: Check this answer by Tivie [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526894/how-to-get-get-requests-url-makes-using-php)

Comment: This is not exactly the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: PHP don't know what request the client does to other servers (like a third party CDN). It only knows what requests it gets to it's own server. If you want to get it in JS, then it depends on how you make those calls. Please be more specific about what you're trying to do though. Exactly when do you want what to print where? We need details and we also want to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? How does stub.en.js is requested?

Comment: As in the picture, I want to print the URL shown by the Request URL in the network field in the browser.