# Get XML string from string with headers

Tags: xml, wsdl, mime-types, soap-client

I have response from WSDL Service in XML format with headers (service was done bad but I don't have any influence on that). Response looks like that:

```
  --uuid:5ef54ff9-16d1-4675-823a-f692be71a142+id=295
  Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>M
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitM
  Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"

  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/ZalogujResponse</a:Action></s:Header><s:Body><ZalogujResponse xmlns="http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07"><ZalogujResult>s4e4c8u5h4s7s4y6z6p6</ZalogujResult></ZalogujResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
  --uuid:5ef54ff9-16d1-4675-823a-f692be71a142+id=295--
```

Now i need to get only XML string from that response. I know that i can explode and get it from array or just parse after 2nd apperance of "<" but I want to do it more global... Because that way if they will add any header or remove it my scripts would stop working so it's dangerous solution. Is there a better way to do it ?
I have Symfony2 Application (PHP).

Comment: In which language you handle the response?

Comment: Symfony2 with PHP ;-)

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request) will help you.

Comment: I don't use CURL. If I would it would be easy - just setting CURLOPT_HEADER to false. But like I said before I get that from WSDL service (using SoapClient).

Answer (score 0):

Till now I have found only the following solution to fix [MTOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism) used with [XOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-binary_Optimized_Packaging):

```
    $response = 'YOUR XML STRING....'; //WSDL Response (with CURL or SOAP)

    //if resposnse content type is mtom strip away everything but the xml.
    if( strpos($response, "Content-Type: application/xop+xml") !== false){
        $tempstr = stristr($response, "<s:Envelope");
        $response = substr($tempstr, 0, strpos($tempstr, "</s:Envelope>")) . "</s:Envelope>";
    }
    return $response;
```