# Getting cookie for PHPUnit ajax test

Tags: php, session, cookies, phpunit, session-cookies

I'm trying to write some PHPUnit tests for ajax endpoints. I can do this no sweat when the user doesn't have to be logged in. But to test the endpoint in question, the user does have to be logged in and I want to get the cookie programmatically as part of the test. Basically the test I want to run looks like:

```
    $url = "https://example.com/ajax/endpoint";
    $fields = array(
        'name'=>'test '.rand(),       
        'host'=>rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255).'.'.rand(0,255),
        'port'=>rand(1,1000)
    );
    $fields_string = "";
    foreach ($fields as $key=>$value) {
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    ob_start();
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $userCookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $this->assertEquals(true, $response);
    $json = ob_get_contents();
    $return = json_decode($json);
    $this->assertEquals('false', $return->success);
    $this->assertEquals('', $return->data);
    ob_end_clean();
```

But I don't know a good way to get `$userCookie` other than opening a browser, logging in, and then reading `PHPSESSID` from the cookies in the browser. How can I get the cookie for this without grabbing it manually? I'd like to be able to get it from a curl request to the login endpoint:

```
    $url = "https://example.com/ajax/login";
    $fields = array(
        'username'=>$username,
        'password'=>$password
    );
    $fields_string = "";
    foreach ($fields as $key=>$value) {
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I do not have a solution for your problem at hand. But when I see the words unittest ajax call in the same sentence, I get suspicious. Unittests should not access network/IO or any other system boarders.
Try mocking the network access or do the test in an integration test.

Comment: You should add the curl tag. Also, like @lukassteiner said, this really is an integration test because you're both dependent on the network/IO and the session/login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does anything stop you to grab it programmatically?

```
$ch = curl_init('https://example.com/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=root&password=toor");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=(.*?);/mi', $result, $matches);
$userCookie = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there with your login cURL request. What you need to do is retrieve the cookie from the response headers to get the `PHPSESSID`.

How to get response headers with cURL has been asked in another question you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request).

Once you've got the response headers, you'll have to parse it to get the `Set-Cookie` header. Using the content of that header for your subsequent tests should work from there.