# return value from closure without reference

Tags: php

I am using the curl option `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` along with a closure to perform some basic data manipulation. As per the php docs, the function / callback must return the length of the header on each call.

```
    $headers = [];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($curl, $headerLine) use (&$headers) {
        $headers[] = $headerLine;

        return strlen($headerLine);
    });

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $headers;
```

I am using references to return the value which works fine. I am just curious if there are other ways to return this value without using references or using a callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the callback function to be a class method:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'someOtherFunction'));
```

In that other function, you can have access to anything `$this` has access to:

```
protected function someOtherFunction($curl, $headerLine)
{
    $this->headers[] = $headerLine;

    return strlen($headerLine);
}
```

<sub>* This answer assumes you're inside of a class context to begin with</sub>

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering if it is possible without a callback function either. Interesting you can just use `$this`, I think I used `&$this` initially.

Comment: If you want to use `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` then it takes a callback, no way around that. If the only thing you want to do is look at the headers of a response, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9183272/697370)