# JQuery/Javascript to get the Http Header detail of given URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Is it possible to get the HTTP Header detail for any URL by using javascript?

Below URL refered to the curren page, where as I need to get the header detail for any given URl (like http://www.facebook.com)

[Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: @teeyo That's the same page he referred to in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this purely in Javascript because of the AJAX same-domain restriction.

The best way would be to write a server-side script that accesses the URL using cURL. See [Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request) for how to extract the headers from the response in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

you can use XMLHTTP.getAllResponseHeaders()
  or getResponseHeader("header name")

e.g.

```
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
xmlhttp=null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7, Firefox, Opera, etc.
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
if (xmlhttp!=null)
  {
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=state_Change;
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  }
else
  {
  alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP.");
  }
}

function state_Change()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
  {// 4 = "loaded"
  if (xmlhttp.status==200)
    {// 200 = "OK"
    document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML=xmlhttp.status;
    document.getElementById('A2').innerHTML=xmlhttp.statusText;
    document.getElementById('A3').innerHTML=xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders();
    }
  else
    {
    alert("Problem retrieving XML data:" + xmlhttp.statusText);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't generally work because of the AJAX same-domain restriction.

Comment: And several headers are explicitly unavailable to XHR

Comment: The OP linked to a question which already says this in the accepted answer. The problem they are asking about is the cross origin problem.