# download a file from PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl

I have this code in my curl:
$data_string = json_encode($data);

```
$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                                                       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'User-Agent: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    'X-Forwarded-For: '.$this->getIp()
));      

$result = curl_exec($ch);
return $result;
```

I am getting this giberish result:

[image]

I am expecting an image file.

Question here is that how can i download this image file?

Comment: That **is** an image file! More specifically, a JPEG picture.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes I am well aware of that. Question is how can I download this one? or maybe echo the file into my browser.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this code

```
$profile_Image = $url; //image url
$userImage = 'myimg.jpg'; // renaming image
$path = '';  // your saving path
$ch = curl_init($profile_Image);
$fp = fopen($path . $userImage, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This works like a charm, if you want it to be downloaded automatically, you can add this code : 

$content = file_get_contents($path);
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'mime/type');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=filename.pdf');

$response->setContent($content);
return $response;

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
$data=send_curl($url);
$path='./test.jpg';
$file = file_put_contents($path,$data);
```

the function of send_curl

```
function send_curl($url, $data, $PROXY = "") {
  $ch = curl_init ();
  if ($PROXY != "") {
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $PROXY );
  }
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
  curl_close ( $ch );
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, browsers decide how to display a given piece of content using the information of the `Content-Type` HTTP header and PHP can generate HTTP headers with the [header()](http://php.net/header) function.

If you know for sure that your picture will always be in JPEG format it's rather straightforward:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo your_download_function();
exit;
```

Otherwise, you need to fetch the header returned by the remote server. Curl has a tricky syntax—I refer you to [PHP cURL retrieving response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request)