# PHP - IP Canonicalization test

Tags: php, redirect, ip, canonicalization

This is code for getting site's IP

```
$ip = gethostbyname(parse_url('http://www.wikipedia.com', PHP_URL_HOST));
print_r($ip);
```

but, what is the proper way to check with php does the website's IP redirects to site's domain?

EDITED:
It seems I wasn't clear enough in my first question. The question is based on seositecheckup.com test. One of the warning there says:

IP Canonicalization Test
Your site's IP 198.35.26.96 does not redirect to your site's domain name. This could cause duplicate content problems if a search engine indexes your site under both its IP and domain name.

So, I'm asking how would I check by myself if the site's IP redirects to site's domain, in PHP

Comment: Possibly others will have other ideas, but I think you'd need to use CURL function to check response headers. A quick google on "curl response headers" and... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request

Comment: @DuaneLortie so you are saying to check IP's headers or?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you try to do

Comment: To be sure the domain name and the IP result in the same content.. I'd
fetch via curl the domain name, check for redirects,and if response is 200, make a checksum of that content, then do the same for the IP.. I don't know any other way to detect a 301/302 redirect other than w/ CURL

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

The question says one thing, but the code implies another ...

- If you're looking to do an IP-to-hostname lookup, there's another function for that: [gethostbyaddr()](https://secure.php.net/gethostbyaddr)
- If you did indeed mean "redirect" when you said it, you'll have to use an HTTP client library (like cURL) to see whether `http://ipAddress/` returns a 30x status code and a `Location` header pointing to the hostname-based URL.

Comment: Can I do that with get_headers, not with curl?

Comment: Yes, that's possibly the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a reverse IP lookup.

The `gethostbyname` do forward IP address and [`gethostbyaddr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) do the reverse IP lookup.

An code example would be:

```
$ip = gethostbyname(parse_url('http://www.wikipedia.com', PHP_URL_HOST));
print_r($ip);
$domain = gethostbyaddr($ip);
print_r($domain);
```

Comment: This will output: text-lb.esams.wikimedia.org