# display the content of HTTP response headers

Tags: php, api, http, curl

I want to print out the contents of HTTP response headers. Here is the code:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');

print_r(json_decode($result, true));
```

The allow_url_fopen is 'On' in php.ini. I have tried the same with the curl extension of Php. The code was right but it printed nothing.Can anyone explain me why is it so?

Comment: That's because the contents from `http://www.google.com` isn't a valid json to be decoded. Use `print_r($result);` instead and see if it works.

Comment: No it doesn't solve my problem. It takes me to the google webpage. I want the contents of HTTP request such as status code, status text, header information etc.

Comment: What I'm showing to you is that everything is ok with your request, your server can comunicate with google and get a valid response. So, obviously, your problem is with your code which doesn't do what you want to do. What output do you expected?

Comment: An array which contains the contents of the request made.

Comment: It seems to me that you are not exactly sure about what you want.  Could you update your question with your expected output?

Comment: output of type  `/* output:
stdClass Object
(
[status_code] => 200
[status_txt] => OK
[data] => stdClass Object
(
[long_url] => http://sitepoint.com/
[new_hash] => 0
)
)
*/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133567/discussion-between-jot-waraich-and-felippe-duarte).

Comment: this is not a request header but a response header

Comment: use curl to do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request

Comment: Sorry i said request. surely it is a response header. I did the same with curl but it was also not showing anything.

Answer (score -1):

file_get_contents is for literally getting the contents of the file.  Based on the info provided it sounds like you want to call http://www.google.com and obtain the http status code.  You need to use something curl, not file_get_contents. There are tons of tutorials and info on curl like this [one](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)