# wont allow post request - 405 error

Tags: php, html, post, get, http-status-code-401

I found a script and modified it, hoping to returrn the contents of a login page. However, it seems that the page won't let me log in.

using `var_dump($_POST);` and `print_r($_POST);` gives me a blank array:

```
array(0) {
}

Array
(
)
```

So I don't know how to do it. The website is https://create.kahoot.it/login

This is the code I am running:

```
<?php
$username = 'USERNAME';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$loginUrl = 'https://create.kahoot.it/login';


//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set URL 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
//HTTPS
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
//try to echo post variables
var_dump($_POST); 
print_r($_POST);
//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);

//Handle cookies
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
// to return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

//login
$store = curl_exec($ch);
//put page details in file
file_put_contents("test.txt",$store);

?>
```

--EDIT--

- response headers + authentication page stuff
  [image]
- by changing the postman from POST to GET it returns `{"error":"Authentication failed","exception":"Authentication failed","error_description":"Authentication token of type [class no.mobitroll.core.security.shiro.tokens.SessionToken] could not be authenticated by any configured realms. Please ensure that at least one realm can authenticate these tokens.","timestamp":1499789957919,"duration":0,"errorCode":0}`

Comment: well, if you actually watched what that form is doing (via your network tab), when you submit the form it sends the POST request to https://create.kahoot.it/rest/authenticate, not the URL you've got above - that's only the landing page containing the form. Forms don't have to post back to themselves! 405 means method not allowed, and given that the URL there is just a form, it's understandable that they don't allow POSTs to it. Of course there's no guarantee changing the URL will work, they might have anti-spoofing measures in place, but you can only try.

Comment: I get a `301 Moved Permanently`, but we are moving in the right direction! All my details were empty still, though

Comment: normally a 301 response will contain a link to the location the resource was moved to. e.g. `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/index.asp`. A browser would respond to this automatically and request that new URL immediately, but cURL does not do that. You need to extract that location (either programatically each time, or by hand and then change your script to hard-code the new URL) and POST to that instead.

Comment: Well, It doesn't tell me a URL unless `openresty/1.11.2.2` is it.

Comment: The full html returned is: `<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.11.2.2</center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: it's usually in a "Location" header, not in the response body. Do it manually on the website, like a normal user, with your browser's network tab open, or using an intermediary tool like Fiddler might be easier. Watch what happens, you can see the sequence of requests and responses that happen, and then you know what you need to emulate.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what a `location header` is. Can we output that from PHP?

Comment: read about HTTP headers then, if you don't know what that is. Every HTTP request and HTTP response contains both headers and body sections. Look at the requests in your browser or in Fiddler as I just suggested and you can start to see the structure. The PHP/cURL documentation will explain how to extract the headers from a response using PHP.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request for ways to get the headers from cURL

Comment: Wow! That worked. What sections do we need? At the end it says `Curl_http_done: called premature == 0`. Is that a problem?

Comment: I don't really know cURL that well if I'm honest, you might be able to google that error, but as I said earlier you ought to be looking inside the header info for a header called "location".

Comment: There is no such header. Do you want the full text?

Comment: Hm if so that means their API is not really observing the convention properly. Strange that a login process would have a 301 in it at all, but there you go. Anyway yes show me the whole text in case you've missed something.

Comment: `*   Trying 23.22.203.63...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to create.kahoot.it (23.22.203.63) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.kahoot.it
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
> POST /rest/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: create.kahoot.it
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 45
`

Comment: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 45 out of 45 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
< Server: openresty/1.11.2.2
< Date: Tue, 11 Jul 2017 15:08:35 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 124
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host create.kahoot.it left intact`

Comment: What's interesting is by changing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`  to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);`, it changes the IP to `54.211.216.59`

Comment: that's the output of the cURL command line, not the response headers from the resulting HTTP response.

Comment: It might be easier to use a tool like PostMan to create the request and get the response initially, it will give you a clearer view of the response than cURL. Once you know what to expect back from the server it'll be easier to write your PHP code. https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: i got them. I will add it to my originial post

Comment: @ADyson you still there?

Comment: 401 means you can't authenticate. Possibly this is some anti-spoofing stuff. However I'd be surprised if it accepts a GET instead of a post. Can you show the response for when you send a POST please?

Comment: I got it to work. I needed to post in the form of `application/json` and I needed a third field.

Comment: `$loginheader = array(); 
$loginheader[] = 'content-type: application/json';
$loginpost = new stdClass();
$loginpost->username = $username;
$loginpost->password = $password;
$loginpost->grant_type = "password";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($loginpost));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$loginheader);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
`

Comment: ah well done, well spotted! That would make sense, since it expects the form to be submitted via ajax normally, and that technique would quite often use JSON to send data.

Comment: In fact, I'm having the problem again, if you want to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044027/405-error-php-get-request

Answer (score 0):

first use this code and debug your issue.

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r( $info );
```

**if you are requesting HTTPS** check

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

405 error probably for un-permitted methods. e.g. Making a GET call, when only POST is permitted, or vice versa.

Comment: does it matter where

Comment: It returns nothing. Here we go:

Comment: print before your curl_close($ch);

Comment: `(
    [url] => https://create.kahoot.it/login
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => 0
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
`

Comment: `[size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)`

Comment: See my comment above, you've missed the real reason this doesn't work

Comment: So it could not be a post request? How can I tell? `https://create.kahoot.it/rest/authenticate`

Comment: and also check  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); Hope it works .