# 405 error php get request

Tags: php, get, http-status-code-405

I have this script and I want to make a request to a page, but it gives me a 405 help. Here is my code:

```
$result = "SOMETHING"
$kahootId = '0c17fb60-76c6-424c-9326-d1154cbc70d3';
$pageUrl = 'https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/' . $kahootId;
$quizheader = array(); 
$quizheader[] = 'content-type: application/json';
$quizheader[] = 'authorization: ' . $result;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pageUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,$quizheader);

$store2 = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($store2);
curl_close($ch);
```

This code returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: openresty/1.11.2.2
Date: Tue, 11 Jul 2017 20:53:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 150
Connection: keep-alive

{"error":"javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException","exception":"javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException","timestamp":1499806383136,"duration":0,"errorCode":0}
```

This code was based off of this python script:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6609181/2464424)?

Comment: @user2464424 the problem is, I have no data to send!

Comment: Oh I need a get request

Comment: Have you tried to not pass the `content-type: application/json` header also?

Comment: looking at the output response seems like either an error on api server not your side or you are not making the proper request in which case read the api docs

Comment: Well, I added an image on what it's based off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is a GET request with custom headers and no body, you can use the following method that doesn't even need Curl:

```
$token = "SOMETHING"
$kahootId = '0c17fb60-76c6-424c-9326-d1154cbc70d3';
$url = 'https://create.kahoot.it/rest/kahoots/'.$kahootId;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'header'  => "Authorization: ".$token."\r\n"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```