# Keep same filename when downloading from google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm downloading a file through php script and everything work perfectly except one ugly truth. The downloaded file keep the same url and with original name appended. How do I maintain the same filename when file downloaded?

```
$file = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc';
download($file);

function download($url) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    header('Expires: 0'); // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($r)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    echo $r;
}
```

Comment: What filename do you mean? Can you specify more precisely what you want the file to be named in your example?

Comment: i want the php code work with multiple urls

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135574/4875631). Basically you want to capture the [Content-Disposition header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) (Which should contain the filename) via google, and relay that back to the client:

```
function download($url) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = [];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    // this function is called by curl for each header received
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
      function($curl, $header) use (&$headers)
      {
        $len = strlen($header);
        $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
        if (count($header) < 2) // ignore invalid headers
          return $len;

        $name = strtolower(trim($header[0]));
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $headers))
          $headers[$name] = [trim($header[1])];
        else
          $headers[$name][] = trim($header[1]);

        return $len;
      }
    );

    $r = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    header('Expires: 0'); // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: ' . $headers['content-disposition']);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($r)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    echo $r;
}
```

Comment: i got a file php to download