# PHP get_headers() to generate the header file

Tags: php, html, curl

I am working on getting the header response codes for a list of urls. I need the output to be like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` etc.

Using cURL - I used this command `curl -s -I https://www.pnc.com | grep HTTP` (or) `curl -I https://www.pnc.com 2>/dev/null | head -n 1`. And, I get the output as `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

Using PHP - I used get_headers() command to do the same in PHP. And I'm getting the output as `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`.

This is the code that I used.

```
$line = "https://www.pnc.com";
$myheader = get_headers($line,1);
echo "$myheader[0]";
```

After running this, I get the output as `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`. Can someone give any suggestions?

Comment: Because that's what the site responds with? `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` and `Location: https://www.pnc.com/en/`

Comment: See the note here ~ http://php.net/manual/function.get-headers.php#100113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command line invocation using curl is following the 301 redirect and then returning the headers of the redirected page. For a more reliable approach using curl from PHP I suggest you use a variation of my answer over here:

[Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request/41135574#41135574)

If you wish to transparently follow the redirect as curl is doing on the command line, set the curl option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, for example:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Since you are not interested in the body, turn off the return transfer option, ie:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
```

If you wish to perform a `HEAD` request set the following option also:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. When I added the HEAD request set it gives me the correct output. Thank you again.