# What on my PHP Curl call do I need to add to read a response's custom headers?

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers

I tried a few several ways to read the responses custom header but have not been able to. I know the response I get is served by nginx and the custom header names start with X-......

```
$endpoint =  'url here';
$ch = curl_init( $endpoint );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'cbFunc');                                                                    


$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r( curl_getinfo($ch ) );
```

Comment: Show what you tried (in your question) along with describing the actual result vs the expected result.

Comment: ok @PatrickQ I updated w/ my code sample above

Comment: Have you read the documentation for these things? Are you aware of what `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request)

Comment: @miken32 what should the callback function I write  do?  do you have sample code

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) is an excellent reference guide an a good starting point when you run into problems like this.

> **CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION** [Set value to] A callback accepting five parameters.

hence

```
log_headers('init');
$endpoint =  'url here';
$ch = curl_init( $endpoint );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'log_headers');                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$headers=log_headers();
print_r($headers);

function log_headers($ch=false, $headers=false)
{
    static $hdrs;
    if (is_array($hrs) && $ch===$headers===false) {
        return $hdrs[];
    } elseif ($ch==='init') {
        $hdrs=array();
        return 0;
    } 
    $hdrs[]=$headers;
    return strlen($headers);
}
```

Comment: Whoops - copied/pasted the wrong description, should be 2  - Thanks miken32

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '===' (T_IS_IDENTICAL) in /app/catalog-sunbutter-feed.php on line 22  is code right