# how to get curl response header

Tags: php, curl, header, response

I want to use curl and post method then I want to get response header (not response source) like set-cookie etc
How can I do this?
I created the below code but it only shows response source:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, 
    CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);  //Post Fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 1);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

echo ($server_output);
```

I tried `getinfo($ch);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request)

Comment: Please show us the full code you tried. The `curl_setopt($ch, ` bit should make this code fail