# Card Connect get X-CardConnect-SessionKey from response header

Tags: php, curl, header, response-headers

**What is the issue?**

We need to extract X-CardConnect-SessionKey from the response header of Card-Connect API. We are using **v2/connect** [API](https://developer.cardconnect.com/bolt-p2pe#connect) of CardConnect through **PHP-CURL** method.

**What we have done to extract the header?**

We are using below methods of PHP to get the headers from the response

get_headers | getallheaders

***Passing the below parameters in the CURL request:***

CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,

CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,

CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,

CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => 1,

CURLOPT_NOBODY => 1,

**Our Observations.**

When we call the same API from PostMan we are able to see **X-CardConnect-SessionKey** in the response header, but when we dump full header using the above methods not getting that same key highlighted in below screen-shot.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request

Comment: (`getallheaders` won’t help you here, that is for getting the _request_ headers of the current request that triggered your PHP script.)