# Pass user request (headers, etc.) to external URI

Tags: javascript, php, security, request, http-headers

**Preface**:

We have written some software that allows our users to embed the content of many of their webpage building tools directly into their websites. For instance, our clients use a medley of Landing Page or "Funnel" building tools. Many of these tools are pretty antiquated and don't have a native way to bring that content elsewhere, and our clients don't like to send users to `our-client.some-landing-page-builder.com/landing-page`.

We have developed some software that will fetch the content at `our-client.some-landing-page-builder.com/landing-page`, do some work on the `action`, `src`, etc. attributes (some of these tools use relative URLs and wouldn't change them to absolute for us), and then it gets embedded directly into their website, `our-client.com/landing-page/`. It uses an optional cache or microcache to make sure that the content is fresh, and it has been working excellently for years.

**The Problem**:

When a user visits `our-client.com/landing-page/`, and the software makes a request to the content on the Landing Page builders, the request that is sent belong to the `our-client.com` and not the user that visited the site. For most of our clients, this isn't an issue.

**The Question:**

We have one client in particular that is asking if there's a way to send that user's request headers from `our-client.com` to `some-landing-page-builder.com`?

Comment: Do you mean to extract headers and store it somewhere, or you mean redirecting the request with original headers to a new location? For extracting headers you may use e.g. `getAllHeaders()` or most of crawler software should be able to extract headers - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request .

Comment: I wasn't away of that, I'll take a look, thanks! But I suppose I mean something more along the lines of directly simulating a request from the user to a third party URI, without actually redirecting the user it.

Comment: Could you use PHP's `getallheaders()` or `apache_request_headers()`, encode the resulting array (e.g. into a JWT), and then pass that as an additional header e.g. `X-Original-Request-Headers` to the next service?