# Fetch all products on shopify store using shopify's API & PHP

Tags: php, api, shopify

Currently i can fetch as per shopify's API limit of 250 products per call and echo this out. I have done some research and found that i need to paginate the request on the overall count of products [5000 products / 250 products per page = 20 pages] in the store.
I want get all products in shopify
so I tried to solved.
but i can not get all products.
the result is always 'error.....'.what is problem?

```
    $pages = ceil($products_cnt->count/250); // Count products / 250 
    for($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++){
        $api_url = 'https://apikey:password@store.myshopify.com';
        $get_url = $api_url . '/admin/products.json?limit=250&page='.($i+1);
        $products_content = @file_get_contents( $get_url );
        if (!empty($products_all)) {
            print_r('ok');
        } else {
            print_r('error.....');
        }
        $products_json = json_decode( $products_content, true );
        $products = $products_json['products'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a problem with [Shopify API rate limit](https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/rate-limits). But to be sure of this need to check the response from the Shopify API. For the HTTP request better to use the [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or some HTTP client package for example the [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

Try instead of the `@file_get_contents($get_url)` use this code:

```
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

  $products_content = curl_exec($ch);

  if(curl_errno($ch)){ 
     print_r('Curl error.' . curl_error($ch));
  }
  
  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  if(in_array($status_code, [200, 201])){
     print_r('ok');
  } else {
     print_r(
          'Shopify API error. ' .
          'HTTP Code: ' . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . '; '
          'Error:     ' . $products_content
     );
  }
  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Or you can just use the PHP SDK for the Shopify API requests - https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify

Answer (score 0):

The Pagination method you are trying to use has been deprecated. Shopify introduced new cursor based pagination from API version 2019-07. To read more about Cursor based pagination, head over to Shopify Docs for [Cursor based Pagination](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/make-paginated-requests-to-rest-admin-api). It is better if you use some PHP library that offers rate limiting and other things. However, a sample implementation using cURL would look something like below. Check code comments for details.

```
<?php
// username and password for API
$username = "";
$password = "";

$nextPage = NULL;

$curl = curl_init();

// set result limit and Basic auth

curl_setopt_array(
    $curl,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://store-name.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-07/products.json?limit=50",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password

    )
);

// call back function to parse Headers and get Next Page Link
curl_setopt(
    $curl,
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
    function($curl, $header) use (&$nextPage) {
        $len = strlen($header);
        $header = explode(':', $header, 2);

        if (count($header) < 2) // ignore invalid headers
        return $len;

        if (trim($header[0]) === "Link" && strpos($header[1], 'next') !== false) {
            $links = explode(',', $header[1], 2);

            $link = count($links) === 2 ? $links[1] : $links[0];
            if (preg_match('/<(.*?)>/', $link, $match) === 1) $nextPage = $match[1];
        }

        return $len;
    }
);

// First request

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
    print_r($error_msg);
}
$parsedResponse = json_decode($response);
$result = $parsedResponse->products;

// generate new requests till next page is available

while ($nextPage !== NULL) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $nextPage);
    $parsedResponse->products = [];
    $nextPage = NULL;

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $parsedResponse = json_decode($response);

    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
    } else {
        $result = array_merge($result, $parsedResponse->products);
        sleep(2);
    }
};
echo "Products Count: ";
echo count($result);
curl_close($curl);
```

Response Headers parsing function by [Geoffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41135574/2803788)