# Filter out json string from Curl output string datatype data

Tags: php, json, curl

I am having the following curl option array:-

```
array
(
    [10002] => <the url>
    [13] => 260
    [19913] => 1
    [52] => 1
    [81] => 0
    [64] => 0
    [10036] => GET
    [10018] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
    [42] => 1
    [10023] => Array
        (
            [0] => cache-control:no-cache
            [1] => Connection:keep-alive
            [2] => Cache-Control:no-cache
            [3] => Accept:*/*
        )

)
```

More precisely, with such options:-

```
array
(
    [CURLOPT_URL] => <the url>
    [CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] => 260
    [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] => 1
    [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] => 1
    [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] => 0
    [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] => 0
    [CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] => GET
    [CURLOPT_USERAGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
    [CURLOPT_HEADER] => 1
    [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] => Array
        (
            [0] => cache-control:no-cache
            [1] => Connection:keep-alive
            [2] => Cache-Control:no-cache
            [3] => Accept:*/*
        )

)
```

I tried to display the output like this:-

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
```

The result I get is this:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Set-Cookie: SDPSESSIONID=78AD999FC8ED2A5797F9897781C469BE; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: sdpcsrfcookie=3a634909-ad8c-4f8d-9d3e-2553066603a2;path=/;priority=high
Set-Cookie: _zcsr_tmp=3a634909-ad8c-4f8d-9d3e-2553066603a2;path=/;SameSite=Strict;priority=high
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: private,no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 190
Date: Thu, 18 Feb 2021 13:30:04 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Connection: keep-alive

{"response_status":{"messages":[{"type":"success","message":"Approvals fetched","status_code":"200"}],"status":"success"},"approvals":[],"list_info":{"filter":{"name":"MyPendingApprovals"}}}
```

Now, in the result we can see a json string.
But how can I filter this json string from the original output?

When I tried to var_dump the data, I get the result like this:-

```
string(744) "HTTP/1.1 200 
Set-Cookie: SDPSESSIONID=63933314372DEC341F173537C5B96801; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: sdpcsrfcookie=bcae7824-0186-4cd3-9eec-57d4950cf0ab;path=/;priority=high
Set-Cookie: _zcsr_tmp=bcae7824-0186-4cd3-9eec-57d4950cf0ab;path=/;SameSite=Strict;priority=high
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: private,no-cache,no-store,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 190
Date: Thu, 18 Feb 2021 13:58:51 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Connection: keep-alive

{"response_status":{"messages":[{"type":"success","message":"Approvals fetched","status_code":"200"}],"status":"success"},"approvals":[],"list_info":{"filter":{"name":"MyPendingApprovals"}}}"
```

Also, is there any way where I can only get the proper json string as output? Like, do I need to send any useragent for this.

Comment: `CURLOPT_HEADER` will return the headers as well. If you have no use of them, set this flag to false.

Comment: Here's a question that shows how to [parse the body out of a full response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request), just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `CURLOPT_HEADER` from `1` to `0` or `false`. CURLOPT_HEADER returns the header along with the response data. See more at [CURLOPT_HEADER explained](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADER.html)

Your code should be something like this.

```
$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"; // replace with your own

$config = array
(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 260,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0, // set it to 0 or false
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "cache-control:no-cache", 
        "Connection:keep-alive", "Cache-Control:no-cache", "Accept:*/*" )
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $config);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
```