# Shopify REST API Pagination Link Empty

Tags: php, curl, shopify, php-curl, shopify-api

**Situation**

I am trying to make a call to the **Shopify REST API** where I have more than 50-250 results but I am not able to get the **Link** Header from the cURL Response which contains the **Pagination Links**.

Sample of Link Headers from the [API Documentation](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/make-paginated-requests-to-rest-admin-api) for Cursor-Pagination (https://shopify.dev/tutorials/make-paginated-requests-to-rest-admin-api)

```
#...
Link: "<https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{version}/products.json?page_info={page_info}&limit={limit}>; rel={next}, <https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{version}/products.json?page_info={page_info}&limit={limit}>; rel={previous}"
#...
```

The link **rel** parameter does show up, but the Link is empty as below.

[image: This is as per my PHP Code]

My Shopify Call function

```
function shopify_call($token, $shop, $api_endpoint, $query = array(), $method = 'GET', $request_headers = array()) {
    
    // Build URL
    $url = "https://" . $shop . ".myshopify.com" . $api_endpoint;
    if (!is_null($query) && in_array($method, array('GET',  'DELETE'))) $url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($query);
    
    $headers = [];
    
    // Configure cURL
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    // this function is called by curl for each header received
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
      function($ch, $header) use (&$headers)
      {
        $len = strlen($header);
        $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
        if (count($header) < 2) // ignore invalid headers
          return $len;
    
        $headers[trim($header[0])] = trim($header[1]);
    
        return $len;
      }
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Sphyx App v.1');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');

    // Setup headers
    $request_headers[] = "";
    if (!is_null($token)) $request_headers[] = "X-Shopify-Access-Token: " . $token;
    
    $request_headers[] = 'Accept: */*'; // Copied from POSTMAN
    $request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'; // Copied from POSTMAN
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

    if ($method !== 'GET' && in_array($method, array('POST', 'PUT'))) {
        if (is_array($query)) $query = http_build_query($query);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    }
    
    // Send request to Shopify and capture any errors
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $response = preg_split("/\r\n\r\n|\n\n|\r\r/", $result, 2);
    $error_number = curl_errno($curl);
    $error_message = curl_error($curl);
    


    // Close cURL to be nice
    curl_close($curl);

    // Return an error is cURL has a problem
    if ($error_number) {
        return $error_message;
    } else {

        // Return headers and Shopify's response
        return array('headers' => $headers, 'response' => json_decode($response[1],true));

    }
    
}
```

But when I use a **POSTMAN Collection**, I get a proper formatted response without the **Link** getting **truncated/processed**.

[image: This is the Header when I use a Postman Collection]

I have tried a lot of things here available via the StackOverflow Forums as well as Shopify Community, but I'm unable to parse the Response Header the same way as shown by API Examples or POSTMAN

***My issue does seem to be with the PHP Code, but I'm not a pro with cURL. Thus, I'm not able to make it further :(***

Also, I'm not able to understand why POSTMAN's Headers are in **Proper Case** whereas mine are in **Lower Case**

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: if I use var_dump($result) from the curl call, the "link" header shows a string of 300+ length which clearly means the error is in parsing/processing.

Comment: Hi there, 

Any luck for this? I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 8):

Found my answer :
https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Help-with-cursor-based-paging/m-p/579640#M38946

I was using a browser to view my log files.  So the data is there but it's hidden because of your use of **'<'s** around the data.  I had to use the browser inspector to see the data.  Not sure who decided this syntax was a good idea.  Preference would be two headers that one can see and more easily parse since using link syntax is not relative to using an API.

My suggestion would be 2 headers:

**X-Shopify-Page-Next: page_info_value** (empty if no more pages)

**X-Shopify-Page-Perv: page_info_value**  (empty on first page or if there is no previous page).

Easy to parse and use.

But having this buried as an invalid xml tag, having them both in the same header and using 'rel=' syntax makes no sense at all from an API perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Need to get header like

```
$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = htmlspecialchars(substr($response, 0, $header_size));
```

Here is complete solution
https://miraclewebsoft.com/shopify-rest-api-pagination-link-empty/