# How to get response headers with `download.file`?

Tags: r, curl, download, http-headers, rcurl

I have R 4.20+, so I believe `utils::download.file` is using capability `libcurl`.

I can get the headers of a url with `base::curlGetHeaders(url)`.

Is there a parameter I can pass in `download.file` to return the headers, so I can't get them in the same call.  Under the hood, `download.file` is processing the header somehow, as it is receiving it.

How to return response headers I get with `curlGetHeaders(url)` from the function `download.file`?

I am aware of external packages (e.g., `Rcurl`) but for the download to occur, the headers have to be received within `R:::base`.

### Update

Here is the source code from R

```
"libcurl" = {
           headers <- if(length(headers)) paste0(nh, ": ", headers)
           status <- .Internal(curlDownload(url, destfile, quiet, mode, cacheOK,
                        headers))
       },
```

The function `curlDownload` has traditional curl options here (`libcurl.c`):

```
curl_easy_setopt(hnd[i], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

That sets the header, not return it.  Why are the raw `curl` functions not publicly exposed.  `C` exposes them as does `PHP`... see

[Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
// ...

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

So I guess `curlDownload` needs:

```
curl_easy_setopt(hnd[i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

#### library (curl)

In this library, under the hood, the same syntax is being used.  How to expose the syntax directly to me?  From `download.c`:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, NULL);
  curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL);
  curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doc mentions the handle_data function, within the curl package.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/curl.pdf

For example, suppose you need to peek at the status code, content type or other headers before reading all the lines. Once you have a working connection, many other functions in R will accept that ... you can use the various `read.csv(x)`, `read.delim(x)`, `scan(x)` and so on.

```
library('curl');
h <- new_handle();
x <- curl('https://cran.r-project.org', handle=h);
open(x);
handle_data(h)$status_code;
handle_data(h)$type;
parse_headers(handle_data(h)$headers);
y <- readLines(x);
close(x);
```