# How to get WordPress posts count using PHP Curl

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using php curl API to fetch the posts from WordPress. But I'm not getting X-WP-Total or X-WP-TotalPages keys with response to work with pagination.
$curl = curl_init();

```
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Accept: application/json',
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With"
        ],
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    // print_r($response);exit;
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Those are response _headers_, you won't find them inside the response _body_.

Comment: @CBroe How I'm supposed to get that value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request