# CURL and PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser with object

Tags: php, image, parsing, curl, dom

Using CURL and [Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/index.html) to get content from website. Getting response in object. I'm using it to get the link of all images from the product page of this website https://www.geekbuying.com/
It works with most pages, this one for example https://www.geekbuying.com/item/eufy-MACH-V1-Cordless-Vacuum-Cleaner-520574.html

With other pages, which are in fact identical, it doesn't get anything and I just can't figure out why. This one for example https://www.geekbuying.com/item/eufy-Clean-G40-Hybrid--Robot-Vacuum-Cleaner-520591.html

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$link = "https://www.geekbuying.com/item/eufy-Clean-G40-Hybrid--Robot-Vacuum-Cleaner-520591.html"; //don't works

$link = "https://www.geekbuying.com/item/eufy-MACH-V1-Cordless-Vacuum-Cleaner-520574.html"; //works


function get_content($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom->load($htmlContent);
    foreach($dom->find('img') as $element){
        $immagine = $element->src;
        echo "$immagine <br />";
    }
}

get_content($link);
```

The script should allow me to get the link of all the images in an external page, but with some it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe they dont want you scraping their site without permission

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is the reason. The pages have the exact same structure, only the contents that draw from the database change.

Comment: So what debugging have you done? "just don't get anything" isn't a useful description for us. Do you mean you get no HTML returned at all from the page? Or just that you can't find the specific items you want? Have you checked the raw response to the cURL request? It wasn't really clear from the description what you've narrowed the issue down to.

Comment: To restate things, you can generally have a cURL problem or an XML problem, but rarely (or probably never) both.

Comment: sites are huge could be out of memory issue, enable error reporting. i hate myself for saying this but you could use regex for such simple "parse"

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself badly. The structure of the product page is always the same https://www.geekbuying.com/item/eufy-MACH-V1-Cordless-Vacuum-Cleaner-520574.html the contents change according to the product being viewed. With most pages the script fetches all the urls of the images. With some pages, on the other hand, it gets absolutely nothing.

Comment: "The script" is the general PHP as a whole. What we are asking you is if cURL is returning empty data, or if the problem is in simple XML. The posted code pipes data pretty much directly from cURL to HTML processing without checking the contents.

Comment: If I write echo "$htmlContent";
for most pages it prints all the html, for those where the error is present it prints nothing.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, so we can rule out the XML/HTML processing completely and focus solely on the cURL. You should add some code along the lines of `if(!$htmlContent){/*Whatever you need to do, such as throw an Exception*/}`

Comment: You should be inspecting the HTTP readers returned, it is possible that you are being given more information about the problem. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183272/231316