# Problem using curl to read data and header value

Tags: php, curl

I am using Curl to get a request from an REST API. Here my Code:

```
<?php
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pasw=$_POST['pasw'];

$data = array(
'userName' => $user,
'systemCode' => $pasw   
);

$json = json_encode($data);
$url = 'https://aaaaaaa/login';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //riga per leggere header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json)
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $response;
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

the answer is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: product only
Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2024 19:05:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 68
Connection: keep-alive
x-trace-id: 5977480715868404720
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-span-id: 5977480715868404720
xsrf-token: x-ffffffffffffcbu5ik59g87tdo83teory
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=x-ffffffffffffcbu5ik59g87tdo83teory;Path=/;Secure
upcase-conversion-headers: accessSession

{"data":null,"success":true,"failCode":0,"params":{},"message":null}
```

so text and json. I should pass the value 'xsrf-token:' to the calling page. Can you help me understand how? thanks

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? The header is everything before the blank line. Split that into lines, and loop over it looking for the one that begins with `xsrf-token:`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Could you tell me how in PHP?

Comment: [Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9183178/2943403)